# deleting every nth element from a list in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have been given a task to create a code for. The task is as follows:

> You are the captain of a sailing vessel and you and your crew have
>   been captured by pirates. The pirate captain has all of you standing
>   in a circle on the deck of his ship trying to decide in which order
>   you should walk the plank. Eventually he decides on the following
>   method:
>
> (a) The pirate captain asks you to pick a number N.
>
> (b) The
>   first person to walk the plank will be the Nth person (starting from
>   you).
>
> (c) The captain will then continue around the circle forcing
>   every Nth person to walk the plank.
>
> (d) Once there is only one person
>   left, that person will be given freedom.
>
> For example: The crew
>   consists of: Andrew, Brenda, Craig, Deidre, Edward, Felicity, Greg and
>   Harriet. Andrew selects N=2. The crew will walk the plank in the order:
>   Brenda, Deidre, Felicity, Harriet, Craig, Greg, Edward. Andrew will be
>   given freedom.

The code i have so far is:

```
def survivor(names, step):
    names =  ["Andrew", "Brenda", "Craig", "Deidre", "Edward", "Felicity", "Greg", "Harriet"]
    Next = step - 1
    names.pop(Next)
    print names
```

This will remove the first nth person from the list but I'm not sure how to loop through the list to keep removing the nth person.

I need it so lets assume step = 3, then i need it to remove craig and then count from craig onwards and remove the next 3rd element which is felicity and so on until there is one person left.

How can I do this?

Comment: So the person who makes a choice is always the first in the list?

Comment: i have used my own code for the first part which is: Next = step - 1 while len(names) > 1: names.pop(Next) Next = Next + step Next = (Next - 1) % len(names) print names return names[0] that works to return survivor but when i try to implement the second part suggested aswell it doesnt seem to work
 
i have tried to use this: assert name in names for step in survivor(names, step): if survivor == name: but it doesn't work it says UnboundLocalError: local variable 'step' referenced before assignment return step

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
from collections import deque
def survivor(names, step):     
    circle = deque(names)
    while len(circle) > 1:
        circle.rotate(1-step)
        print circle.popleft()
    return circle[0]
```

It prints the names of the pirate's victims and returns the name of the survivor:

```
In [17]: crew = ["Andrew", "Brenda", "Craig", "Deidre",
   ....: "Edward", "Felicity", "Greg", "Harriet"]

In [18]: survivor(crew, 2)
Brenda
Deidre
Felicity
Harriet
Craig
Greg
Edward
Out[18]: 'Andrew'

In [19]: survivor(crew, 3)
Craig
Felicity
Andrew
Edward
Brenda
Harriet
Deidre
Out[19]: 'Greg'
```

Comment: Thank you Lev, this works perfectly. You dont know how much i appreciate this, i been stuck on this for ages. THANK YOU

Comment: @user1839493 This will only be of help if you understand how it works instead of just handing it to the teacher (sorry if I guessed wrong). Also, you can [mark the answer as accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/181223) if it solved you problem.

Comment: can you then explain the deque part to me please?

Comment: @user1839493 [`collections.deque`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque) is an object that I used to implement the "circle" in this case. It is much like a list, but can be easily accessed from both ends and has a `rotate` method. Please look at the documentation page I link to for description of `rotate` and `popleft`.

Comment: lev if it not too much to ask can you hep me with thos aswell
i need to create a function called safeN that uses a loop and the function above to find the smallest N to save the crew member entered for def safeN(names, name):

Comment: @user1839493 This is definitely too much to settle in comments. I suggest you take some time and try to figure it out yourself. Hint: You can use `survivor` in a loop with increasing `step` until the result is the desired name, then the value of `step` is the answer. If you have any trouble, please post another question.

Answer (score 1):

The following code should do everything that you asked for, including implementing the `safeN` function:

```
import collections
import itertools

def walk_plank(names, N):
    "Walk everyone down the plank."
    circle = collections.deque(names)
    while circle:
        circle.rotate(-N)
        yield circle.pop()

def save_last(names, N):
    "Save the last person from walking the plank."
    for name in walk_plank(names, N):
        pass
    return name

def safeN(names, name):
    "Find the best N to save someone from walking the plank."
    assert name in names, 'Name must be in names!'
    for N in itertools.count(1):
        if save_last(names, N) == name:
            return N
```

**Edit:** Here is some example usage of the code up above while working with IDLE in Windows.

```
Python 3.3.0 (v3.3.0:bd8afb90ebf2, Sep 29 2012, 10:55:48) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> import collections, itertools
>>> def walk_plank(names, N):
        "Walk everyone down the plank."
        circle = collections.deque(names)
        while circle:
            circle.rotate(-N)
            yield circle.pop()

>>> def save_last(names, N):
        "Save the last person from walking the plank."
        for name in walk_plank(names, N):
            pass
        return name

>>> def safeN(names, name):
        "Find the best N to save someone from walking the plank."
        assert name in names, 'Name must be in names!'
        for N in itertools.count(1):
            if save_last(names, N) == name:
                return N

>>> names = 'Andrew Brenda Craig Deidre Edward Felicity Greg Harriet'.split()
>>> tuple(walk_plank(names, 2))
('Brenda', 'Deidre', 'Felicity', 'Harriet', 'Craig', 'Greg', 'Edward', 'Andrew')
>>> save_last(names, 2)
'Andrew'
>>> safeN(names, 'Andrew')
2
>>> safeN(names, 'Brenda')
19
>>> save_last(names, 19)
'Brenda'
>>> tuple(walk_plank(names, 19))
('Craig', 'Harriet', 'Andrew', 'Felicity', 'Deidre', 'Edward', 'Greg', 'Brenda')
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help Noctis Skytower, I can now implement the second part of the task

Comment: i have used my own code for the first part which is:
Next = step - 1
    while len(names) > 1:
        names.pop(Next)
        Next = Next + step
        Next = (Next - 1) % len(names)
        print names
        
    return names[0]
that works to return survivor but when i try to implement the second part suggested aswell it doesnt seem to work

Comment: i have tried to use this:
assert name in names
    for step in survivor(names, step):
        if survivor == name:
but it doesn't work it says UnboundLocalError: local variable 'step' referenced before assignment

            return step

Comment: @user1839493: Make sure you are using Python 3.3 to run the code. An example of the code's use will be given.