# code for walking the plank python

Tags: python

did you ever get the code to work for walking the plank I have failed so far to get a doctest to work on the codes I have

```
def survivor(names, step):
    """
    >>> survivor([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],3)
    7
    >>> survivor(["Andrew", "Brenda", "Craig", "Deidre", "Edward", "Felicity", "Greg", "Harriet"], 3)
    'Greg'
    >>> survivor(["Andrew", "Brenda", "Craig", "Deidre", "Edward", "Felicity", "Greg", "Harriet"], 1)
    'Harriet'
    >>> survivor(["Andrew", "Brenda", "Craig", "Deidre", "Edward", "Felicity", "Greg", "Harriet"], 6)
    'Andrew'
    >>> survivor(["Andrew", "Brenda", "Craig", "Deidre", "Edward", "Felicity", "Greg", "Harriet"], 2)
    'Andrew'
    >>> survivor(["Andrew", "Brenda", "Craig", "Deidre", "Edward", "Felicity", "Greg", "Harriet"], 4)
    'Felicity'
    >>> type(survivor([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],3))
    <type 'int'>
    >>> type(survivor(["Andrew", "Brenda", "Craig", "Deidre", "Edward", "Felicity", "Greg", "Harriet"], 3))
    <type 'str'>

    """

def survivor(names, step):
    names = ["Andrew", "Brenda", "Craig", "Deidre", "Edward", "Felicity", "Greg", "Harriet"]
    next = step - 1
    names.pop(next)
    print names

import collections
import itertools

def walk_plank(names, N):
    "Walk everyone down the plank."
    circle = collections.deque(names)
    while circle:
        circle.rotate(-N)
        yield circle.pop()

def save_last(names, N):
    "Save the last person from walking the plank."
    for name in walk_plank(names, N):
        pass
    return name

def safeN(names, name):
    "Find the best N to save someone from walking the plank."
    assert name in names, 'Name must be in names!'
    for N in itertools.count(1):
        if save_last(names, N) == name:
            return N
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem here?

Comment: Looks like it was a post from another support forums, which presumably has context.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13477969/17776

Comment: well my code seems to be fine as far as i can see its the uni want us to doctest it and its not running properly

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
def survivor(names, step):
    step -= 1 
    Next = step
    while len(names) > 1:
        names.pop(Next) 
        Next = (Next + step) % len(names)
    return names[0]
```